# Firebase : How to send to groups of devices on the fly

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Our Firebase server currently uses a one device per topic.  However as users of the App are increasing the overhead of sending many topic sends is starting to be significant.  What are our options for grouping sends, given that the targets dataset changes on every send.

We started to look at device groups, but these will be unsupported if we are forced to move to HTTP V1.  We had considered just adding a group of users to a topic, but managing the lifespan of the topic could become an issue.  We would have to create a new one on every send, working out at what point we could tear this subscription down with impacting any messages which have not been received may be problematic.

And suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual approach for this is to either use topics, or implementing your own topic-like system. In the latter you'd store the relation between the Instance ID and your grouping logic in a database, and then use the [batch-sending feature of FCM](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#send_a_batch_of_messages) to deliver to up to 1000 devices at a time.

Comment: Frank, thanks for this, the 'group logic' is entirely transient, so if I can use AppIIDs (which I can recover in the dataset) that is ideal.  I have been using https with json and the fcm URL up until now, and have noticed that some features (live device sending) will not be supported on HTTP v1.   Are you aware of any such restrictions (in particular for batch sending using SendAllAsync()) when going via the API (rather than using URLs?).  Also can I confirm that the limit of targets to send to is 100, rather than 1000, or am I missing something.  Thanks for your response.

Comment: I'm not sure what live device sending means. Do you have a link to docs for it?

Comment: Sorry, Typo.  I meant like "device group" sending.  See https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/migrate-v1

Comment: There's indeed no support for device groups in the (new) versioned API. The idea there is that you define your own grouping, and use the batch send functionality to accomplish the same goal.